# Double click Nestable List

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-events, double-click, jquery-nestable

I need to change an element from a list between the two list I have,
with a double click,

but I don't know how to do,

actually I can change an element with a click and drag them to another list with that script :

```
    $('#ranked').nestable({
    group: 1,
    maxDepth: 1
}).on('change', function () {
    $.post('/jackfolio/saveEpic', {
        ranked: window.JSON.stringify($('#ranked').nestable('serialize')),
        unranked: window.JSON.stringify($('#unranked').nestable('serialize'))
    }, function (data) {
        $('#update-info').text('Info de maj: ' + data);
    });
});
$('#unranked').nestable({
    group: 1,
    maxDepth: 1
});
```

Can you help?

Comment: I need to precise I use Nestable List Plugin for my two List drag and drop !

Comment: Fixed ! You can delete sorry for this post :)